# Transparent PNG in WebView on Android

Tags: android, webview, png

I have some PNG files with transparent backgrounds that I want to put in a web page to view in an Android WebView. The WebView is set to have an image as a background. I've noticed the transparency works in, say, Google chrome, even on the cell phone itself, but the images come up with a white background in my WebView. Here is the markup for the page:

```
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="teststicker1.png" style="background-color:transparent;"  />
    <img src="teststicker2.png" style="background-color:transparent;" />
    <img src="teststicker3.png" style="background-color:transparent;"/>
    <img src="teststicker4.png" style="background-color:transparent;"/>
</div>
```

How do I achieve transparency so the background falls through to the background of the WebView instead of being white? I've searched this site and found similar questions but none quite the same, and none of the answers there worked.

The code for initializing the WebView is

```
myWebView.loadUrl(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.site_url)+getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.image_picker_html));
myWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_gallery_2_2);              
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

[image]

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After loading the content on your webView** set the background color for the webview to transparent using this:

```
yourWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Clear cache everytime after creating web view in your code to avoid loading of cached pages. (point pulled from my comment below)

```
yourWebView.clearCache(true);
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally accepted your answer. I may accept it in the future but I haven't tried this yet. Thanks.

Comment: myWebView.loadUrl(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.site_url)+getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.image_picker_html));
          myWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_gallery_2_2);        
          myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

still shows the white background. The page itself has a transparent background but not the images.

Comment: is `myWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_gallery_2_2);` required? what is this drawable? is it a white background?

Comment: It's green with some gradient. The drawable is visible around the images, but not in the transparent background of the images.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you see and the above code to your question? It would be easier to read there with formatting.

Comment: have you considered replacing the png altogether and checking if it is a problem with the png image? If not, do check that out.

Comment: Strange, it seems that it's caching the page. I changed the web page, it's different in the browser but not in the app.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall then

Comment: also u could clear cache everytime after creating web view in your code `yourWebView.clearCache(true)`

Comment: Thanks I was looking for how to do that and didn't see your comment until now. After reloading, *everything has a transparent background*. Seems that was my real problem. *Now* I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);